# Is it possible to return multiple rows from a Spark User Defined Aggregate Function (UDAF)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to return multiple rows from a Spark UDAF in the same way that flatMapGroups allows you to return multiple rows after doing a groupByKey on a Dataset? High Performance Spark mentions that UDAFs are a more performant alternative to mapGroups so I was wondering if there was a more performant alternative to flatMapGroups

I know that could return a list and then explode it but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: You can use an ArrayType as the return type and append to it an but be warned it slows down considerably

Comment: won't that still return a single row?

Comment: Yes, you will have to use the explode function then

Comment: Or use a dummy gruoping variable to groupBy and apply the udaf to get the rows